# How to display values from HashMap for records from SQLite effectively?

Tags: android, android-listview

**The goal:** The application should allow the user to add a quantity for the displayed items. Think about creation of the order of products from a list of all possible products. The code list of products can be very long (like tens of thousands of items or even more). On the other hand, the number of selected item for the order is very small (like several or tens at maximum).

**Already implemented:** So far, I have implemented the `OrderOverviewActivity` that uses `LoaderManager` and the content provider for accessing the information from the database. I do use `MyCursorAdapter` that extends `CursorAdapter` and overrides its `newView()` and `bindView()` methods.

The `newView()` creates also a `ViewHolder` instance with references to child view and with buffers for the values extracted from the cursor position -- like this:

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView code;
    public CharArrayBuffer codeBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(20);

    public TextView name;
    public CharArrayBuffer nameBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(100);

    public TextView quantity;
    public CharArrayBuffer quantityBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(10);
}
```

The `newView()` looks like that:

```
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = mInflater.inflate(mLayout, parent, false);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.code = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.code);
        holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.quantity = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

        v.setTag(holder);

        return v;
    }
```

The `bindView()` uses the holder buffers to avoid creation of many `String` objects:

```
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        cursor.copyStringToBuffer(1, holder.codeBuffer);  // ProductTable.COLUMN_CODE
        cursor.copyStringToBuffer(2, holder.nameBuffer);  // ProductTable.COLUMN_NAME

        holder.code.setText(holder.codeBuffer.data, 0, holder.codeBuffer.sizeCopied);
        holder.name.setText(holder.nameBuffer.data, 0, holder.nameBuffer.sizeCopied);

        // The quantity (v for value) from the HashMap<String, String>.
        String v = mQuantity.get(String.valueOf(holder.codeBuffer.data, 0,
                                 holder.codeBuffer.sizeCopied));
        if (v != null) {
            holder.quantity.setText(v);
            holder.quantity.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
        else {
            holder.quantity.setText(null);
            holder.quantity.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
```

**Core of the question:** Notice that the quantity is extracted from the `HashMap<String, String>` object via `String.valueOf(data, 0, data.size)`. I am afraid it creates a string object that must later be garbage collected later thus spoiling the performance. Is there any better way to set the quantity TextView value from the map?

Comment: Have you actually profiled it? Don't just guess its an issue, measure it! Checkout Traceview http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html and Systrace http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html to get started

Comment: As smith324 already pointed out you should first make sure that you have a problem and that the problem is that single `String` instance creation(which I really doubt is the case). To get around you could simply use the `HashMap` with a `CharArrayBuffer` key(of course this would require to change other part of the code as well) or remove the `HashMap` and replace it with a `SparseArray` and make the `_id` column the key.

Comment: @smith324: Consider this a test of it can be done better. Actually, I will not use the `HashMap` in the final implementation. I am just curious if the same case could be solved better. Anyway, +1 for the references.

Comment: @Luksprog: I did not try, but I guess the `CharArrayBuffer` cannot be used as a key as it is not hashable. But the `SparseArray` could work for the case. Thanks and +1.

Comment: Yes, `CharArrayBuffer` can't be used as a key, my bad(and it's also final so you can't take matters into your own hands). The simplest solution would be, as I said above, to use the `_id` from the cursor to identify the rows(so you'll use a `HashMap<Long, String>`) doubled by another `HashMap<Long, String>`(which will contain a map of the row id to the actual name). You can further abstract this into a class wrapping the two maps so it's easier to access the values/ update synchronously the two maps etc. This will come with a small increase in memory but there's always a drawback either way

Comment: @Luksprog: Thank you for helping me understand the problem. Please, elaborate on your last comment; think about my related comment below the http://stackoverflow.com/a/18113410/1346705, put it together, and write the answer. I will accept it if there is no other surprising idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would disagree with yanchenko about the `CharArrayBuffer`, it's a nice improvement to use in the `Cursor` based adapters(and especially when the `Cursor` has many `String` columns to use). To get rid of that extra `String` the first option would be to make it the key for the `mQuantity` `HashMap` which will not work(and the class it's `final` so you can't make it work at all).

The other way around to identify rows is the `_id` column required by the `ListView` anyway.

Related to this you could:

- Have two `HashMap`s both having as a key a `Long` value(the _id) and one will hold the `COLUMN_CODE` and the other will hold the actual quantity(or one map mapping between the `_id` and the code and the other being your current map). This two maps would be synchronized(if you remove one value for a long id you remove it from the other as well, the same when you add values etc). In the `getView()` method you would then get the name by using the _id from the `Cursor`, this however would require an autoboxing operation(`long` to `Long`).

  ```
  class DataWrapper {
   private HashMap<Long, String> mCodeMapping = new HashMap<Long, String>();
   private HashMap<Long, String> mQuantityMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();

   public String getCode(long id) {
        return mCodeMapping.get(id);
   }

   public String getQuantity(long id) {
        return mQuantityMapping.get(getCode());
   }

   public String getQuantity(String code) {
        return mQuantityMapping.get(code);
   }

   public void put(long id, String code, String quantity) {
       mCodeMapping.put(id, code);
       mQuantityMapping .put(code, quantity); 
   } 
  }
  ```
- Although the `_id` is a `long` and you have a decent amount of values you could threat it as an `int`(as you'll be in the boundaries of the maximum `int` values). Doing this will allow you to simply use a `SparseArray` with a custom class(casting between `long` and `int`):

  ```
  class WrapperData {
   String code; //or use the CharArraybuffer?
   String quantity;
  }

  SparseArray<WrapperData> data = new SparseArray<WrapperData>();
  // in the getView() method 
  WrapperData wd = data.get((int) _id_value); // further use wd.code or wd.quantity
  ```
- The last option is to implement your own class like `SparseArray` which will allow you to have a mapping between a simple `long` key(so no autoboxing) to the code and quantity values.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using the `_id` as the key of the `HashMap`. I do not need two synchronized `HashMaps`. The `code` was used only as the key to find the value. Also, the `code` value for the view is in its view holder (`codeBuffer`). The `SparseArray` could be a good option, in my opinion. Actually, I will not use that approach. For various reasons, the implementation will use another database table for the quantity values (i.e. more *standard* solution). Anyway, thanks a lot for helping me understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add string variable into the ViewHolder class, as cloned memory instance allocated for your Holder class and mapped with position. As well as just done assign value use NEW keyword so you will get new STRING object which is not mapped with HASHMAP.

private static class ViewHolder 
{

```
public String quantityStr;

public TextView code;
public CharArrayBuffer codeBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(20);

public TextView name;
public CharArrayBuffer nameBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(100);

public TextView quantity;
public CharArrayBuffer quantityBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(10);
```

}

public View newView

{
   ...
  holder.quantityStr = **new String**( mQuantity.get(String.valueOf(holder.codeBuffer.data, 0,             holder.codeBuffer.sizeCopied)) );

}

Comment: In my opinion, it does not change the problem. The `String` variable stores just reference to a `String` object that had to be created, anyway. The goal is not to create `String` instances if it can be avoided.

Comment: You need something(variable) to hold that value and later it will be mapped with textview, isn't it?

Comment: As well as, why you are not using "public CharArrayBuffer quantityBuffer" which is in your code.

Comment: I need to use the value as the key for the `HashMap`. For the purpose, the `CharArrayBuffer` cannot be used, because the object is not hashable. Therefore, it must be converted to another object that is hashable and that returns the same hash as the content of the `CharArrayBuffer`. My goal was to avoid creation of the `String` instance, but it may be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

i think it will not create a new string instance, because there is already a string constant which existed in string constant pool.

```
String str = "test";
String str2 = "test";
char[] strArray = {'t', 'e', 's','t'};
System.out.println(str.hashCode());
System.out.println(str2.hashCode());
System.out.println(String.valueOf(strArray).hashCode());
```

the result is same as blow:
3556498
3556498
3556498

Comment: The same hash code cannot be used as a proof of identity. It only says that the content is the same.

Comment: yes, it's true. but as you described, not matter using CharArrayBuffer or String directly. you always need instantiate one string instance from database.

Comment: you use string  instead of CharArrayBuffer in class ViewHolder, holder.string1 = cursor.getstring(columnName). the rest we can use reference holder.string1

Comment: I understand that, but then it makes no sense to put the string reference into the holder. The `ViewHolder` instance makes sense only when the objects refered inside are instantiated once and reused many times, in my opinion. The trick is that the content of the cursor can be just copied into the `CharArrayBuffer` instance without the need for creation of another `String`. I am not sure what do you mean when writing about *string pool*.

Comment: as the above snippet, when we define a new string constant(note, it is constant not object), jvm will research in string pool if there is constant already, if yes, jvm will not create a new string. but it seems like nothing to do with your case. my question is that you used charArrayBuffer instead of string in viewHolder, have you even compared the memory? which one is more efficient. i am not so sure

Comment: cursor data copied into charArrayBuffer or String

Comment: Concerning the memory space for storing a sequence of characters, both will be comparable. The difference however is, that the memory space inside of the `CharArrayBuffer` is reused. The `ListView` recycles the `View` objects used for displaying and uses about that many of them that can be visible in one time. This way also `ViewHolder` objects are recycled, and the same quantity is used. Their `CharArrayBuffers` are therefore also recycled. To compare, when using `String` objects and scrolling through all list items, those object must be created and later garbage colected.

Comment: there is container named recycler, when we scroll up the listview, OS will add the passed one to the recycler instead of recycle it. for the new one, OS will check if there is view instance existed in recycler, and return it to bindView(). so when we scroll up the listivew, it doesn't mean newView() will be executed. the view will be reused, we just need te rebind it every time.

Comment: Yes. I know that. Are you asking or telling anything? To summarize, I definitely consider the `ViewHolder` approach with `CharArrayBuffer`s more memory and time efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather not mess with `CharArrayBuffer`s and use `String`s + `TextView`s in the `Holder`.

This way you'll make the code more readable and let the platform use String pool for caching. Which will also mean optimal performance.

I.e.

```
private static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView code;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView quantity;

}

public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    String code = cursor.getString(1);
    String name = cursor.getString(2);

    String quantity = mQuantity.get(code);

    holder.code.setText(code);
    holder.name.setText(name);

    if (quantity != null) {
        holder.quantity.setText(quantity);
        holder.quantity.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    } else {
        holder.quantity.setText("");
        holder.quantity.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

}
```

I'd recommend you to run a series of 3 profiling tests first:

1. Without `String v =
   mQuantity.get(String.valueOf(holder.codeBuffer.data, 0,
   holder.codeBuffer.sizeCopied));` call at all.
2. Initial version.
3. This version.

And based on the result choose the most readable one between the last two. (:

Comment: Yes, it is more readable, but the result is less efficient. Correct me if I am wrong. When scrolling the `ListView`, the `String` objects must be created. Then they are thrown away and garbage collected later. (Any string pool will not help here if the strings are not the same.) This way, the scroll through a very long list may be less fluent, slower. (I have seen the technique with `CharArrayBuffer` explained elsewhere, but I cannot find it now -- probably by Romain Guy.)

Comment: It was by Cyril Mottier http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/

Comment: Never make assumptions about performance based on code. You always need to profile first.

Comment: Sorry, but why not? Where all these `String` instances will go? I know that the activity will be one of the bottlenecks, and I need to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: You don't know, you assume, and that doesn't work in performance tuning. There are tons of other objects that will be GCed anyways.

Comment: Well, but it is a *qualified assumption*. In my opinion, it is always better to work with say 20 objects--independently on the size of the problem--than to GC several thousands strings instead. Ad 1) The idea was to use the `codeBuffer` without creating the new `String` object. The code is only a placeholder for another code that I do not know and that was the core of the question. The idea behind was to avoid creation the `String` object.